# Replace in string with specific word exceptions

Tags: regex

I wish to remove the classes from class properties in my PHP project. The string I want to find and replace look like this: `private Selector $Selector;` Keep in mind that the class (in this case "Selector") is variable.

I've already tried coming up with a solution myself, however, this pattern also matches `private function sendEventRelayMessage( Tracker $`

find    `private (.*?) \$\b`

replace    `private \$`

Comment: Instead of `.` use `[^(]` or `[^(\n]`, or just replace `.*?` with `\S+` if you only expect a single word between `private` and `$...`

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Ah sorry. Didn't think of that. I am trying to find and replace inside of IntelliJ So that's Regexp @Toto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a more specific Regex. If we follow [PHP's rules on class name](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class), it gives us a pretty good regex already to check class name. All you need is to remove reserved word and you got yourself a solution.

I've come up with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/mGlCI9/2) that does what you are looking for

```
private ((?!function)[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]+) .+
```

The regex will look for the keyword `private`, followed by a space and any characters that are valid class name caracter. It will filter out the keyword `function` (negative lookahead) then matches a spaces and anything after that.

Here is a more complete explaination on how the regex works.

[image: Regular expression visualization]